# UserManager.SendEmailAsync throws Message.Destination is null

Tags: c#, .net, email, confirmation, usermanager

Im trying to implement email confirmation for user registration using standard UserManager and EmailService.

For some reason while calling UserManager.SendEmailAsync(userId,"","") i have IdentityMessage.Destnation is null...

Here is my EmailService implementation:

```
public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        return SendSupportMail(message.Subject, message.Body, message.Destination);
    }
```

message.Destination is null...

What am i doing wrong?

P.s. i have UserManager with integer`s private keys implemented. Cold it be issue somewhere in here?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means the user does not have an email address. The `message` parameter is created this way:

```
var msg = new IdentityMessage
{
    Destination = await GetEmailAsync(userId),
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body,
};
```

You should check that the user has an email address in the database. If you create your own `UserStore`, check the implementation of `UserStore.GetEmailAsync`.

Comment: Thanks. Actually issue was with my Email prop. I have overriden the base one with my.